Vscode does not connect via ssh
ok, my problem is that, I'm trying to connect to my server from vscode via ssh but when I enter the password, vscode tells me
Deleting old log file in /home/user/.vscode-server/.cli.e170252f76e615dec6ca2cc656aba1570769a5d39.log

Remote CLI generated: 3859153
Waiting for server log...
main: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
main: fork: fork: retry: Resource temporarily not available

This was not happening before and the error main: fork: fork: fork: retry: Resource temporarily not available only happens when I try to connect via ssh from vscode, as my server normally only consumes 5% of the resources and they shoot to 100% when I connect from vscode via ssh.
I tried to connect with other ssh clients like putty, also from powershell and even from the vscode terminal and connects without problems but to open the files with vscode is that I am having the problem, also try from other pc to see if the firewall or other factor could be affecting but still does not let me that way, anyone know what could be happening? Thanks
I'm only want to connect to my server from vscode to edit my code :(
